# Why is this CSS playing up?

Tags: html, css, web

I have a very basic container with a few children `divs` inside, displayed as `inline-block`. All works well until I actually insert content into the children divs. When I have content in them, they seem to move down, for no apparent reason.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/GtPWX/1/embedded/result/) is the fiddle of it all working well.

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GtPWX/embedded/result/) is the fiddle with it all messing up (with the content).

Can someone please tell me why this is happening and how to solve it?

I've been at it for hours but cant seem to figure it out. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `display: inline-block` use `display: block; float: left;`

http://jsfiddle.net/GtPWX/2/

Or you could set `vertical-align: top` on the boxes.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you for saving me an extra few hours work. I'll accept your answer when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align:top` to the boxes.